# Having problems with precision in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def myproc(b,a): 
    return b-(((b*a)/(a*a) if a*a !=0 else 0) *a)
```

b and a are objects of type Vec. The return value is a Vec object as well.

```
>>> myproc(list2vec([1, 1, 4]), list2vec([1, 2,-1])) 
Vec({0, 1, 2},{0: 1.2, 1: 1.4, 2: 3.8})
```

Note: list2vec is to convert the given the parameter from a list to a Vec object

My problem is that I need the values to be returned in full precision. i.e, 1.2, 1.4, 3.8 need to be something like 1.2xxxxx etc.

I could not solve this problem.

Comment: What if 1.4 is the full number? What do you want to display then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to print the data manually using `print` function.

Second, use `format` function which allows to set up precision like in the following snippet:

```
>>> print('{0:.8f}'.format(1.2))
1.20000000
```

Comment: Thanks. It did the purpose in general though could not help in my specific problem due to some other constraints in my case but I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

(This question appears to be from [this course](https://www.coursera.org/course/matrix) for which I am a Community TA)

I'm not sure why you "need" to display results to a specific precision; the grader automatically rounds your answers. If you're missing an answer and `--verbose` isn't helping, you might be better served posting on the course forums.